# How to insert hyperlink in powerpoint slide using Open XML?

Tags: c#, asp.net, powerpoint, openxml, presentation

I have a scenario where I have to replace the certain variables from slide template with tabular data but in this case data and slide text is overlapping and after some research I found out that PowerPoint is not designed for such cases [[MS Link]](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/powerpoint-table-not-moving-when-i-adjust-text-hit/32aa0d48-b629-4571-8429-ce9dc63abab1) (img 1). To overcome this I though instead of replacing the variables with tabular data, I should replace the variable with the link which will point the newly created slide where I can post my tabular data (img 2).

So come back to my question, Is there any way I can write the data without messing the template? OR How can I replace the variable with the hyperlink to the slide?

[image: img 1]

[image: img 2]

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-get-all-the-external-hyperlinks-in-a-presentation) you can do something like this, just adjust to your case and how to find the variable1.

```
    // Open the presentation file as read-only.
    using (PresentationDocument document = PresentationDocument.Open(fileName, false))
    {
        // Iterate through all the slide parts in the presentation part.
        foreach (SlidePart slidePart in document.PresentationPart.SlideParts)
        {
            IEnumerable<Drawing.HyperlinkType> links = slidePart.Slide.Descendants<Drawing.HyperlinkType>();

            // Iterate through all the links in the slide part.
            foreach (Drawing.HyperlinkType link in links)
            {
                // Iterate through all the external relationships in the slide part. 
                foreach (HyperlinkRelationship relation in slidePart.HyperlinkRelationships)
                {
                    // If the relationship ID matches the link ID…
                    if (relation.Id.Equals(link.Id))
                    {
                        // Add the URI of the external relationship to the list of strings.
                        ret.Add(relation.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for you response! Actually Variables are text which I need to replace with the hyperlink which will point out to slide. above code will loop thru the links which is not the case and I don't want to bind hyperlink with external link, it should be new slide (rId1,rId2...)